# In ASP.NET MVC, redirect external URL for run a service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and I have a form page, when user click submit button I want to take all information and send a web service(in background) and show a message page.
Everything is okey but in controller page doesn't run this url.
There isn't any error but is doesn't work.

```
return Redirect("http://ww.example.com./webservices/addlead.php?action=Exp&first_name=" + r.Name + "&last_name=" + r.Surname + "&phone=" + r.Telephone + "&hash=" + r.HashCode);
```

Comment: you're trying to redirect a web service to an external url? I'm pretty sure you can't do that nor is that what you really want to do

Comment: Yes I'm trying to redirect a web service to an external url. How else can I do? The user sees the page unchanged?

Comment: what good would redirecting a web service do? You're telling a process that is a separate request from the clients request to redirect. The only thing that would see the response is the server. If you need to send data to `example.com` then you need to use a `WebClient` to make a post

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a **w** in `www`.

```
return Redirect("http://www.example.com/somepage")
```

But If you want to make a call to the webservice to do something, you should better create a proxy class of it and using that, you can call the webservice.  Make your call, get the results and return the results (appropriate view / json /some other type) back the the user.

You may also look into the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class which has methods to acccess external resources.

Comment: The URL seems just an example instead of a production one, so I would not be so sure that this is an issue.

Comment: you need to create a proxy and call your webservice.

Comment: "create a proxy and call your webservice" Is there any example about it? I can not find.

Comment: when you add your web service as a web reference, VS will create proxies for you.http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet